# Ubuntu internet connection not working

Tags: internet, ubuntu-drivers

I have two problems. The first one is i cant enable my wireless broadcom driver. For that i need an internet connection. I tried plugging in the cable but it just shows like its connecting to wifi. My network interface is eno1. Im dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. Btw it recognizes the device.

EDIT: shameless bump

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: If you read it carefully, you will find an offline guide.

Comment: Ok guys ill try the offline guide an ill try to post the output thanks

Comment: But there are two offline guides for different drivers.